# Using Unsigned int 32 bit in Java?

Tags: java, char, bit, unsigned

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting 32-bit unsigned integer (big endian) to long and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855087/converting-32-bit-unsigned-integer-big-endian-to-long-and-back)

I want to translate this expression in Java

```
char tab[100];
tab[10] = '\xc0';

tab[48] = '\x80';

uint32_t w = 0x67452301;

uint32_t x = 0xefcdab89;

uint32_t y = 0x98badcfe;

uint32_t z = 0x10325476;

a = ((b & c) | (~b & d)) + (*(uint32_t*)(tab+0x00)) + a - 0x28955B88;

a = ((a << 0x07) | (a >> 0x19)) + b;
```

I'have tried this but...

```
char[] tab = new char[64];

 tab[10] = (char) 0xc0; 
 tab[48] = (char) 0x80;
```

but the value is not the right one, is there another way to assign \0x80 in a char[] ?
How can i interprete this kind of cast in java (*(uint32_t*)) ?

Many thanks !

Comment: There is no unsigned 32 bit int in Java.  You have to use long (signed 64-bit) instead.

Comment: And arrays cannot be treated as pointers in Java -- you must use explicit array indexing.

Comment: (Also be aware that chars are 16 bits in Java.)

Comment: And you cannot use casts to convert between types that are unrelated in inheritance.

Comment: (So basically you need to first learn Java and then rewrite the algorithm differently.)

Comment: you can use byte instead of char.

Answer (score 6):

Type `int` is 4 bytes, i.e. 32 bits in java. So the regular 32bits int from C may be translated as regular int in java.

Unsigned int is not supported by java language, so use `long` that contains 8 bytes to represent unsigned 32 bit variables from C.

Comment: "long that contains 8 bytes"? Am I understanding correctly? Long is 64 bits.

Comment: I didn't get it at first but after reading that article it made sense. http://jessicarbrown.com/resources/unsignedtojava.html
also the article uses "& 0xffffffffL" in order to translate to long properly.

Comment: int is 32 bit and long is 64 bit  same in c uint32_t in 32 bit how long and uint32_t will relate each other? because in final result if i have total 8 byte of data then it will increase to 16 byte.

Comment: FYI the URL for the unsigned to java article has changed. the new url is:  http://www.raebear.net/programming/java/unsigned-numbers/