# How to translate casting from C in java?

Tags: java, c, reference, casting

Given the following declaration in C, I can write this

```
char tab[64];
(*(uint32_t*)(tab[0]));
```

In other words, applying this kind of cast `(*(uint32_t*)`

Is there another way to implement this in java to get tab's adress ?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can't even reliably do that in C. The snippet posted does not "get `tab`'s address".

Comment: Java doesn't allow the programmer to see _addresses_, all of that is handled under the hood. So thinking about addresses in a Java mindset isn't really productive.

Comment: This isn't valid C code.

Comment: What are you *ultimately* trying to achieve ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759053/using-unsigned-int-32-bit-in-java .  Not that that thread is intelligible either, but it appears to lead to this one.

Answer (score 4):

Java language does not support direct opertions with pointers (arithmetic etc.). So it is irrational to give developer facilities to work with pointers directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another way to implement this in java to get tab's address ?

No there is not.

In Java a `long[]` and a `int[]` are fundamentally different types, and you cannot pretend that one is the other, or vice versa.

The simple solution is to use shifting and masking to extract the high and low 32 bit parts of the individual `long` values.

Another alternative might be to wrap the array of longs in a `LongBuffer` and then create an `IntegerBuffer` *view* of it.  But that is (IMO) cumbersome, and is really just hiding the shifting / masking that goes on under the covers.

---

A comment points out that the question is really about treating an array of bytes as an array of pointers.

That's not possible either ... and there is NO sensible workaround.  Standard Java does not allow you to turn bit patterns into pointers, or vice versa.  (There are some tricks that you could use to do this, but they are fundamentally unsafe and liable to crash your JVM if you don't get them exactly right.)

Whatever it is you are trying to achieve, you should find a different way to code it in Java.

Comment: It you look at the poster's code, you'll see that his char array is being used to hold uint32_t pointers... how do long and int apply? No amount of masking and shifting will allow you to derive pointers in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the 32-bit int using shifts and masks.

Comment: I would sure like to see you either include an example that is related to the question being asked, or delete your answer. Maybe it's just me being dense, but your answer seems to have nothing whatsoever to using a C array of integers that are apparently pointers, and migrating that to Java.

Comment: The answer is good, if the question **intended** to convert bytes to integers. However, the C code presented only works if a `char` has the size of a `uint32_t*` and then actually points to an integer, all of which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

References in Java are not passive like pointers are in C. The address of an object can change at any time so if the JVM is not aware that a value is a reference it cannot update it correctly.

Answering your question literally, you can use the Unsafe class to do this, but its only useful if you are interested in how object are laid out in memory. Changing the values is likely to lead to random crashes of the JVM.

> Is there another way to implement this in java to get tab's adress ?

If you look at why you are trying to do this you are likely to find that in Java the solution is completely different and doesn't require pointers at all.