# Socket giving incorrect response

Tags: java, sockets, byte, endianness

Below are the parameters to be passed to socket in order to read the data:

```
Parameters : methodname(1 byte), payloadlength(2 byte), payload(2 byte)



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int methodname = 5;
    int payload  = 2151;
    int payloadLength = 2;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3 + payloadLength); // 3 = for method name + length
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // Just to be explicit

    buffer.put((byte) methodname);
    buffer.putShort((short) payloadLength);
    buffer.putShort((short) payload);

    buffer.rewind();
    byte[] result = new byte[buffer.capacity()]; // Could also use result = buffer.array();
    buffer.get(result);

            DataOutputStream classOUTstream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());// socket is already connected
                  classOUTstream.write(result);
                  classOUTstream.flush();

                  InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
                  byte[] data = new byte[100];
                  int count = stream.read(data);
        }
```

Everytime i am getting count as **-1**.

Can anybody help me out to fetch proper data from response.

Regards,
Akash

Comment: Are these pieces of code running on two different sockets, on two ends of a connection? Please separate your client and server code, and make your example reproducible.

Comment: Also, you seem to still be displaying the incorrect code from your earlier question, rather than the correct code that either of the two answers provided.

Comment: Why do you create variable ByteBuffer b? It is used only for calculating length of integer? In Java, length of integer always is 4 bytes.

Comment: @ThoQLuong, That is related to an earlier question. He was trying to put an `int` into two bytes.

Comment: @AkashG, Since your question is about Sockets, it would make sense to post enough code to show a full client and server. As it is, nobody else can run your code because you have not even included the Socket creation code.

Comment: @merlin Hi Merlin.. Thanks for your quickly response... I update this question here please check and send me your suggestion . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467115/read-and-write-bytes-data-packet-via-socket

Comment: Curious duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23467115/207421 but by different author (?).

Comment: @EJP, Looks like one user with two accounts?