# Read and Write Bytes data packet via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to connect Android Device to external device via Socket. Socket Connect to external device successfully.

Now if any data require from external device then send request of byte packet data to socket below order. if external device receive data correct then send byte data in response.

Parameters : methodname(1 byte), payloadlength(2 byte), payload(2 byte).

Now My Code is...

```
         Socket socket = new Socket("local exteranl device ip", 5000);
if(socket.isConnected())    {
         int methodname = 5;
            int payload  = 2151;
            int payloadLength = 2;

            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3 + payloadLength); // 3 = for method name + length
            buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // Just to be explicit

            buffer.put((byte) methodname);
            buffer.putShort((short) payloadLength);
            buffer.putShort((short) payload);

            buffer.rewind();
            byte[] result = new byte[buffer.capacity()]; // Could also use result = buffer.array();
            buffer.get(result);

    DataOutputStream classOUTstream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    // socket is already connected
             classOUTstream.write(result);
             classOUTstream.flush();

     InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
     byte[] data = new byte[100];
     int count = stream.read(data);
}
```

Above Code is Android, i knowing only basic concept of java. i am getting **-1 result** in count.

can any one please suggest me or tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the hard way. Get rid of the `ByteBuffer` altogether and use all the methods of `DataOutputStream`. They are all big-endian. I can't see any mistake but clearly you must be sending something the peer didn't understand so he is closing the connection instead of sending a reply.

Note: `Socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you're testing it.

Comment: Hi EJP , i also try below code as per your suggestion.     classOUTstream.writeByte((byte)methodname);              classOUTstream.writeShort((short) 2);              classOUTstream.writeShort((short) payload);
but getting -1 result.

Comment: So something is wrong with the data. Can't help you further with that. Maybe the payload should be 0x2151?

Comment: Same code in iOS, i debug that and found last final bytes are sending external device is 05000208 67.  and getting response suuccessfully. is help for you ?

Comment: OK well 0x0867 is 2151 in decimal so that isn't it. What you're sending is exactly the same. 'Final bytes' suggests there was something before it. What was that? and why aren't you sending it in this code?